# Insert image in Excel using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, applescript, xlwings

I try to insert an image to Excel using the xlwings / appscript on Mac using the following command :

```
 Sheet('sheet1').xl_sheet.shapes.pictures.open('test.png')
```

But the result is the opening of an Excel workbook with the image code.
I have tried a lot of extensions but not found the correct one.

```
 xl_sheet.shapes.pictures.width
 xl_sheet.shapes.pictures.height
 xl_sheet.shapes.pictures.drop
```

Has someone any idea on how to deal with it and if it exists a documentation for AppleScript with Python?

Comment: If you can wait a few days: the next version of xlwings will come with a `Picture` class implemented.

Comment: @Felix : Thank you Felix ! I will wait the next release.

Comment: Done, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now been released with xlwings v0.5.0:

Example:

```
import xlwings as xw
pic = xw.Picture(1, 'picture_name')  # To manipulate an existing picture
pic = xw.Picture.add('path/to/picture.jpg', sheet=1)  # add a new one
```

See the [docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Pictures.add) for the details.